# read file and replace substrings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I am trying to read a text file with python and remove certain strings from it.
I have written a script, but for some reason it does not do what I would expect.

As a minimal example I have the following text file named `test.txt`

```
Here some random text
with words I want to replace
```

and my python3 script

```
with open(r'test.txt',"r") as text_file:
    content = text_file.read()
    print("the content:")
    print(content)
    
    content.replace("Here","")
    print("The replaced content:")
    print(content)
```

The output is

```
The content:
Here some random text
with words I want to replace

The replaced content:
Here some random text
with words I want to replace
```

So you can see the replacement function did not work. However the following script works:

```
test_text = "Here some random text\nwith words I want to replace"
print(test_text)
print(test_text.replace("Here", "Hello"))
```

the output is as expected

```
Here some random text
with words I want to replace
Hello some random text
with words I want to replace
```

When I tested the type of `text_file.read()` by `type(text_file.read())` the output was `<class 'str'>`. Hence, I have no idea why my script does not work

Comment: Instead: `content = content.replace("Here", "")`

Comment: Python strings are immutable - i.e., they can't be changed. You can however create modified versions of them. That's what str.replace() can do by returning the altered version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `replace()` method *returns* the string. You can fix this by replacing

```
content.replace("Here","")
```

with

```
content = content.replace("Here","")
```

This is also why the second print statement works, since you print the return statement of the replace method.

The reason is that a python `str` is immutable. This means that a string object cannot be mutated. Anything that suggests that it does an "operation" on such a string creates a new instance instead.

Answer (score 1):

.replace() is not an in-place operation. See:

```
string = "text from a string"
print(string)
string.replace('from','in')
print(string)
string = string.replace('from','in')
print(string)
```

Outputs:

```
text from a string
text from a string
text in a string
```